# Selenium common exception Timeout exception Message: timeout Error

Tags: python, selenium

I've been working on an Online status check script for OkCupid. So what happens, if the person I am monitoring logs on OkCupid, the script will detect it based on `<div class="userinfo2015-basics-username-online-icon isOnline"></div>` which shows after they log on. It loops every minute to see if there are any status changes. For the most part it works well, it can go on for 30-40 minutes, but then it crashes. 
The output of the script looks like this:

```
----------------------------------------------
[i] Status   |   Last Checked   |   Update   |
----------------------------------------------
[-] Offline      08-14 18:33:03     60 Sec   |
[+] Online       08-14 18:34:05     60 Sec   |
[+] Online       08-14 18:35:09     60 Sec   |
[+] Online       08-14 18:36:10     60 Sec   |
----------------------------------------------
```

This is the loop:

```
try:
while 1:
        status = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('div')[41].get_attribute('class') # Span Class for Online status
        driver.refresh()
        time_online = datetime.now().strftime('%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        time.sleep(5)
        if status == str('userinfo2015-basics-username-online-icon isOnline'):
            print('[+]  Online'+7*' '+time_online+5*' '+str(update+5)+' Sec   |')
        elif status != str('userinfo2015-basics-username-online-icon isOnline'):
            print(bc.red+'[-] Offline'+6*' '+time_online+5*' '+str(update+5)+' Sec   |')
        time.sleep(update)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('  Exiting\n'+46*'-')
driver.quit()
```

Then the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "okCupid_online_status.py", line 38, in <module>
    status = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('div')[41].get_attribute('class') # Span Class for Online status
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 539, in find_elements_by_tag_name
    return self.find_elements(by=By.TAG_NAME, value=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 985, in find_elements
    'value': value})['value'] or []
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 314, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout
  (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.39.562737 (dba483cee6a5f15e2e2d73df16968ab10b38a2bf),platform=Linux 4.15.0-29-generic x86_64)
```

So I am more wondering if I can raise the exception and bypass the error if that happens, and have my script to continue the loop?

Comment: can you catch that exception and let the loop run again?, also sometimes you could quit the driver and open it again after a while

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for sure, but from my experience,  Timeout exception in Selenium often occurs when the browser page is not responding. Next time it happens, I suggest that you check if that's the case.

If this is indeed the case, then because you're creating a scraper (as opposed to test automation), you should catch the exception and retry. If you were to write test automation I would say that you should report a bug about it, because an unresponsive page is usually a bug in the JavaScript code of the page.